# While or loop not stopping after set integer in python

Tags: python, while-loop

Trying to make a rock paper scissor game with a player versing the computer to refresh knowledge on coding however I can't seem to find what's causing the issue in my while loop. I have it set to finish when either the computer or person reaches a score of 3 but stops whenever the total scores equal 8. Full code is listed below

```
import random

rock = "rock"
paper = "paper"
scissors = "scissors"
humanscore = int(0)
compscore = int(0)
limit = int(3)

comp = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"]

while humanscore <= limit or compscore <= limit:

human = str(input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors, first to 3 wins! "))
answer = random.choice(comp)

if human == answer:
    print("Tie, Computer chose, ", answer)

if answer == rock:
    if human == paper:
        humanscore += 1
        print("You Win!")
    elif human == scissors:
        compscore += 1
        print("Computer Won! Try again")

if answer == paper:
    if human == rock:
        compscore += 1
        print("Computer Won! Try again")
    elif human == scissors:
        humanscore + 1
        print("You Win!")

if answer == scissors:
    if human == paper:
        compscore += 1
        print("Computer Won! Try again")
    elif human == rock:
        humanscore += 1
        print("You Win!")

print("\n Computer Chose: ", answer, "computer score: ", compscore, "Human Score:", humanscore)
```

Comment: Here `while humanscore <= limit or compscore <= limit`—You mean *and*, not *or*. You want to continue the loop for as long as *both* variables are under the limit.

Comment: Unrelated, but: to initialize an int variable simply do this: `limit = 3`, no need to use `int(3)`, etc.

Comment: Also, `input` always returns a `str`; calling `str` on the value is a no-op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in comments, the problem is with the `or` in your break condition. As long as one of the scores is below or equal 3, it keeps running.

For instance, if humanscore = 3 and comp score = 2, both parts of the condition are true meaning it continues.

As soon as humanscore = 4 and compscore = 4, both humanscore <= 3 and compscore <= 3 evaluate to false, meaning it stops => total score is 8.

Hence, the while should be like follows (also it should be `<` instead of `<=`, because you want to stop as soon as one has 3 points):

```
while humanscore < limit and compscore < limit:
```

Comment: Ahh I see now, I kept reading it as "or if" and not comparing the two the way I originally intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sorted out the loop - which if you only want to keep going while the scores are both  below `limit`  is corrected as per schilli's answer - you might like to consider a data structure suggestion:

Make a `dict` that records what choice beats a given choice:

```py
whatBeats = {rock:paper, paper:scissors, scissors:rock}

# then later after choices are made...

if answer == whatBeats[human]:
    # computer win
elif human == whatBeats[answer]:
    # human win
else: 
    # draw
```

(Many decades ago I wrote a sorting program before I had learned about any indexed structure - like arrays - and your current method puts me in mind of that sort of effort).